# Is there $\epsilon>0$ such that $n\log n=\Omega (n^{1+\epsilon})$

Tags: asymptotics

It is obvious that $n\log n=\omega (n)$. But does this necessarily mean that $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $n\log n=\Omega (n^{1+\epsilon})$? My intuition says yes, but I'm not sure what $\epsilon$ should be.

Comment: If there were such an $\epsilon$, then you could divide both sides of the equation by $n$. What would you be left with?

Comment: For all sufficiently large $n$ we'd have $\log n>c\cdot n^{\epsilon}$ for some constant $c$. Is there a reason why this cannot be true?

Comment: If it's still not clear, divide that inequality by $n^\epsilon$. Do you believe that there is a positive $c$ such that $\frac{\log n}{n^\epsilon} > c$? Perhaps computing the limit of the left-hand side (hint: L'Hopital's rule) would help.

Comment: Clear. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Consider writing an Answer to your own question below. I'd be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (Thanks to Antonio Vargas): 
No such $\epsilon$ exists

Proof: Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that  $\exists \epsilon>0$ with $$n\log n=\Omega (n^{1+\epsilon})$$. This would imply that for all sufficiently large $n$ we'd have $$\frac{\log n}{n^\epsilon} > c$$ for some constant $c>0$.
However, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon}}\overbrace{=}^{L'Hopital}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\epsilon n^{\epsilon-1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon n^{\epsilon}}\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{}0$$
So no such constant exists